# config helper bootstrap 4 in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap-4, cakephp-3.x

I have installed cakephp plugin twbs/bootstrap via composer 
`composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0`

was successfully and loaded in `bootstrap.php`

```
Pugin::loadAll();
```

next setting is helper modified,
when I looked config helper bootstrap3 in `elboletaire/twbs-cake-plugin`
the setting helper seem like

```
//in AppController.php
public $helpers =[
'Less.Less',
'BootstrapUI.Form',
'BootstrapUI.Html',
'BootstrapUI.Flash',
'BootstrapUI.Paginator'
];
```

and loading of them in `AppView.php`

```
public function initialize()
{
  $this->loadHelper('Less', ['className' => 'Less.Less']);
  $this->loadHelper('Html', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Html']);
  $this->loadHelper('Flash', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Flash']);
  $this->loadHelper('Form', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Form']);
  $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['className' = 'BootstrapUI.Paginator']);
}
```

the questions, where is config helper bootstrap4, since I'm newbie and interest with twitter bootstrap4 which combine cakephp 3.5.11, thanx for anyone to help me

Answer (score 2):

`twbs/bootstrap` *isn't* a CakePHP plugin, it's just Bootstrap. `elboletaire/twbs-cake-plugin` *is* a CakePHP plugin, and it doesn't support Bootstrap 4 yet.

**https://github.com/elboletaire/twbs-cake-plugin/issues/6**

`FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui` will probably be Bootstrap 4 ready soon, so maybe keep an eye on that.

**https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/pull/207**

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of the Bootstrap 4 plugin:
see **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/tree/develop**
Although it a dev version, it works fine for me.

**update**
released Bootstrap 4 plugin: https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/tree/3.x